# Error while deploying a node app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I used git push heroku command to push my node app to heroku but it shows following errors.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 17, 
column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 17, 
column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 17, 
column 3
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot 
common issues here: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-
node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to guarded-ravine-41633.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/guarded-ravine-41633.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/guarded-
ravine-41633.git'
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong. If anyone could correct me than that would be very appreciated.

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Nikhil <nikhilgupta6532@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start 
test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs 
test/e2e/specs",
    "start":"node server.js",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 5.3.0"
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
     "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
     "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
     "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
     "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
     "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
     "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
     "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
     "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
     "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
     "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
     "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },

  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ] 
}
```

I am currently using Vue.js inside my project along with Node.js and sockets.io with database as Mongodb.

Comment: Looks like your package.json is syntactically invalid. Try running `npm install` locally.

Comment: Your packaga.json fileis invalid. It is clear from the error message `Unable to parse package.json`

Comment: Read though the error and see if you can understand it. It mentions that it `Expected another key-value pair at line 17` on line 17 of `package.json`

Comment: yeah i do some changes in my package.json file following this link but still same error shows up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819810/heroku-error-expected-another-key-value-pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading though the error you provided, it mentions that it during your build process, it expected another key-value pair on `line 17 of package.json`.

I ran your `package.json` through a JSON and found a few issues, as follows -

> **Parse error on line 11**: *You should remove the line break between lines 11 and 12.*
>    `"unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test / unit / karma.conf.js--single - run ",`
>
> **Parse error on line 14:**: *You should remove the line break between lines 14 and 15.*
>    `"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specstest / e2e / specs ",`
>
> **Parse error on line 15:**: *You should remove the comma, since this is the last property of scripts.*
>    `"start": "node server.js"`
>
> **Duplicate key 'start' on line 15:**: *You need to decide whether you want your start script to be
>   `"start": "node build/dev-server.js",`  *OR*  `"start": "node build/dev-server.js",`

Fixing these should solve your build errors.

---

**Corrected `package.js` file**

```js
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Nikhil <nikhilgupta6532@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test / unit / karma.conf.js--single - run ",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test / e2e / specs ",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 5.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },

  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Line 17 is started via "engines" and i have the same version of node and npm mentioned  here which is currently installed on my ubuntu

Comment: Can you change your `package.json` to the validated JSON I provided, retry, then post us any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out you have error . Json error syntax
errors

"unit": all test in same line
same for "lint"

and remove two start and also removed comma in line 17

new file

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Nikhil <nikhilgupta6532@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs",
    "start":"node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 5.3.0"
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
     "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
     "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
     "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
     "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
     "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
     "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
     "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
     "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
     "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
     "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
     "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },

  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ] 
}
```